# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

Tags: drupal-7

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal7.location_instance' doesn't exist: SELECT l.lid AS lid FROM {location_instance} l WHERE (uid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in location_load_locations() (line 968 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\sites\all\modules\location\location.module).

error occurs when i try to enable location module in drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

This error simply means that your database does not exist anymore. Drupal only complains of your "Base Table or View" but in reality, when you check your database you will realise that the entire database is empty.

There is a brief talk of this error on drupal.org but what i have found to solve the problem is to restore the database with a recent backup. Though your drupal installation folder may be intact, the underlying data is gone.

If you do not have a recent backup, then i am sorry you would have to re-install drupal. It is a good practice to make frequent backup of your database